# How to find the indeces of the elements == 0 in a matrix? Each row and column should appear only once

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a 4x4 matrix and want to find the indexes of the `elements == 0`. Using `tf.where(tf.equal(matrix,0))` I get something like:

```
array([[0, 0],[0, 1], [1, 3],[2, 1],[3, 2]])
```

How can I remove `[0,1]` from the list as I only want exactly one element for each row and column.

Is there a way to automatically remove the element, which already exists?

```
matrix    = [[    0.,     0., 12989., 32048.],
            [13292.,  9700.,  4485.,     0.],
            [24344.,     0.,  4125., 45000.],
            [14541.,  2325.,     0., 12795.]]
list_zero = tf.where(tf.equal(matrix,0))
list_zero = [[0, 0],[0, 1], [1, 3],[2, 1],[3, 2]]
```

I would like to have this result:

```
list_zero = [[0, 0],[1, 3],[2, 1],[3, 2]]
```

Comment: What is the logic? You want only the first occurence for each line or what?

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you want to avoid having repeated row or column indices right? But the problem is not well defined, consider `[[0, 0], [0, 0]]`, what should I keep? Or in `[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0]]`, if I discard `(0, 1)` then I will have to discard `(1, 0)` (because I kept `(0, 0)`), however I could have discarded `(0, 0)` and then I would be able to keep both `(0, 1)` and `(1, 0)` (in addition to `(2, 2)`). It is not clear what is the criteria to follow to achieve the result you want.

Comment: Thanks! I have to select exactly 4 indices (for a 4x4 matrix) and all the indices must have a different value for the row and column. In your example `[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0]]` the 3 indices (as it is a 3x3 matrix) are `(0,1), (1,0), (2,2)`. 
Anyway, if there are not more zeros in the matrix as the ones I am looking for, the `tf.where(tf.equal(matrix,0))` works perfectly. But if there are more than expected, I want to discard them. 
In my project, it's given that in the matrix there is at least 1 zero in each row and column and it's not possible that all elements equals zero.

Answer (score 0):

This would fall under a "post processing" kind of approach and just uses a loop with conditionals but it seems to give the answer you need. You could put it in a function and use it on your outputs. This approach prioritizes *row* duplicates and ignores column duplicates.

```
clean_list_zero = []
buffer = []
for idx, item in enumerate(list_zero):
    buffer.append(item)
    if idx > 0:
        if buffer[idx-1][0] == buffer[idx][0]:
            continue
        else:
            clean_list_zero.append(item)
    else:
        clean_list_zero.append(item)
print(clean_list_zero)

>>> [[0, 0], [1, 3], [2, 1], [3, 2]]
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly if it is a numpy array. However, it does not work for tensors. The error message would be `Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn`